# macOS stick Item to the bottom of the sidebar

Tags: macos, swiftui

I'm currently experimenting with SwiftUI development for macOS, and I'm trying to get the same sidebar layout as Apple does in the App Store for example:

[image: App Store Sidebar]

I tried a lot of `Spacer()`, but that just doesn't look right and won't stay at the bottom as I'd like to.
Is this even possible? Especially the grey background when it is clicked.
What would be the better way to do that?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: You could try using `.overlay(alignment: .bottom)` on the sidebar but we won't be able to help without some code

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use the [`.safeAreaInset` modifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/safeareainset(edge:alignment:spacing:content:)-6gwby#), e.g.:

```
struct SidebarView: View {
  var body: some View {
    List {
      // your sidebar items
    }
    .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
      Text("Bottom of nav")
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        .background(.red.opacity(0.3))
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

By using the safe area inset, if your sidebar content ends up growing so that it fills the whole sidebar, you'll always be able to scroll it to see the bottom of the scrollable content (if you used an `.overlay`, that might obscure the bottom of the list).

You do have to take care that if your sidebar *is* long enough to need scrolling, that your inset view has a background that obscures the scrolling content behind it. By default it doesn't have any background at all. In the example above I'm using a transparent red, but material styles would also work.